# Why is controlling shell script not working?

Tags: grass-gis

**I updated my post after I resolved the previous errors, but additional errors were produced.**

I want to create a controlling shell script that contains water.mapcalc within it. The problem is, I do not know how to save a code in a file called water.mapcalc. I'm trying out the [hydrologic simulation](http://grass.osgeo.org/gdp/raster/mapcalc-algebra.pdf).

It is stated in page 12:
"For those wishing to repeat the experiment with GRASS enter the model
code in a file called water.mapcalc then create a controlling shell script."

I understood the instruction as I should save the following in a raster map called water.mapcalc:

```
r.mapcalc water.mapcalc = "water = water + eval(x=elev + water,
    if(x>(y=elev[-1,0]+water[-1,0]),
        -.15*if(elev>y, water, x-y),
        .15*if(elev[-1,0]>x, water[-1,0], y-x))+

    if(x>(y=elev[1,0]+water[1,0]),
        -.15*if(elev>y, water, x-y),
        .15*if(elev[1,0]>x, water[1,0], y-x))+

    if(x>(y=elev[0,-1]+water[0,-1]),
        -.15*if(elev>y, water, x-y),
        .15*if(elev[0,-1]>x, water[0,-1], y-x))+

    if(x>(y=elev[0,1]+water[0,1]),
        -.15*if(elev>y, water, x-y),
        .15*if(elev[0,1]>x, water[0,1], y-x))+

    if(x>(y=elev[-1,1]+water[-1,1]),
        -.10*if(elev>y, water, x-y),
        .10*if(elev[-1,1]>x, water[-1,1], y-x))+

    if(x>(y=elev[1,1]+water[1,1]),
        -.10*if(elev>y, water, x-y),
        .10*if(elev[1,1]>x, water[1,1], y-x))+

    if(x>(y=elev[1,-1]+water[1,-1]),
        -.10*if(elev>y, water, x-y),
        .10*if(elev[1,-1]>x, water[1,-1], y-x))+

    if(x>(y=elev[-1,-1]+water[-1,-1]),
        -.10*if(elev>y, water, x-y),
        .10*if(elev[-1,-1]>x, water[-1,-1], y-x)))"
```

**Should I save the model code in a water.mapcalc raster map as what I did above? or should I save a water.mapcalc file in the /bin folder?** I tried both but it still produced errors.

I already did the said map (water.mapcalc).
and I created the following shell controlling script that needs the file (water.mapcalc). This is the shell script (myscript5.sh) and I saved it in the \bin folder of GRASS:

```
#!/bin/sh
export GRASS_PNGFILE=/tmp/grass6output.png

r.mapcalc water = 120
d.rast water

r.mapcalc < water.mapcalc
d.rast water

r.mapcalc < water.mapcalc
d.rast water

g.copy rast=water,water.1

r.mapcalc < water.mapcalc
d.rast water

r.mapcalc < water.mapcalc
d.rast water

g.copy rast=water,water.2
```

Then, I run the `sh myscript5.sh` in the CMD of GRASS and it produced this message:

```
PNG: GRASS_TRUECOLOR status: TRUE
PNG: collecting to file: C:/Users/Rhen/AppData/Local/Temp/grass6output.png,
GRASS_WIDTH=768, GRASS_HEIGHT=508
/c/Program Files/GRASS-64/bin/myscript5.sh: line 7:
water.mapcalc: No such file or directory
PNG: GRASS_TRUECOLOR status: TRUE
PNG: collecting to file: C:/Users/Rhen/AppData/Local/Temp/grass6output.png,
GRASS_WIDTH=768, GRASS_HEIGHT=508
/c/Program Files/GRASS-64/bin/myscript5.sh: line 10:
water.mapcalc: No such file or directory
PNG: GRASS_TRUECOLOR status: TRUE
PNG: collecting to file: C:/Users/Rhen/AppData/Local/Temp/grass6output.png,
GRASS_WIDTH=768, GRASS_HEIGHT=508
Copy raster <water@PERMANENT> to current mapset as <water.1>
/c/Program Files/GRASS-64/bin/myscript5.sh: line 15:
water.mapcalc: No such file or directory
PNG: GRASS_TRUECOLOR status: TRUE
PNG: collecting to file: C:/Users/Rhen/AppData/Local/Temp/grass6output.png,
GRASS_WIDTH=768, GRASS_HEIGHT=508
/c/Program Files/GRASS-64/bin/myscript5.sh: line 18:
water.mapcalc: No such file or directory
PNG: GRASS_TRUECOLOR status: TRUE
PNG: collecting to file: C:/Users/Rhen/AppData/Local/Temp/grass6output.png,
GRASS_WIDTH=768, GRASS_HEIGHT=508
Copy raster <water@PERMANENT> to current mapset as <water.2>
```

the error is: **water.mapcalc: No such file or directory**. I think there is a problem on how I saved the water.mapcalc file. I do not know what format (raster/.txt/.sh file) and where will I save it (should I also save it in the /bin folder together with my script). I tried all of those and it still did not work. I cannot figure out where the problem is.

Comment: You want to write a shell script that calls x.mapcalc?

Comment: x.mapcalc isn't a grass command, do you want to save the output of a mapcalc command? Syntax may have changed since that document was published (1992).

Comment: I've edited my post. I'm sorry for the wrong post. It is not x.mapcalc, it should be water.mapcalc.

Comment: The code posting contains a series of "funny" characters which are perhaps caused by stackexchange? Let me suggest to also post it at http://osgeo.pastebin.com/ for easier editing.

Comment: Additionally: n='expr$n+1' is lacking white space and has wrong backticks (n=`expr $n + 1`), also while[!=100] isn't correct (white space) etc. Again, pastebin or whatever would be handy so that corrections can be made (maybe post the final version eventually here).

Comment: The myscript2.sh file that I made is identical to what is displayed in this post. The errors that I have received (after I run the sh myscript2.sh), is also identical to what is displayed in this post. I guess it is not caused by stackexchange. There is something wrong with how GRASS reads my shell script. From while[$n!=10], GRASS reads it as while[!=100]: command not found. I do not know what is wrong

Comment: here is the pastebin: http://osgeo.pastebin.com/wpm9k9bZ

Comment: From this user's other question, the code may well have been copied & pasted from a PDF -- this would explain the syntax mangling.

Comment: I edited my post again after resolving the errors, but additional errors were produced. I think there is something wrong with the water.mapcalc/ water file

Comment: The water.mapcalc file should be rather straightforward. However, probably the white space in the directory name causes troubles?

Comment: so the model code is saved as "water.mapcalc"? Where is it saved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the "water.mapcalc" script, called :

```
water = water + eval(x = elev + water, \
if (x > (y = elev[-1, 0] + water[-1, 0]), \
   -.15 * if (elev > y, water, x - y), \
   .15 * if (elev[-1, 0] > x, water[-1, 0], y - x))+ \
 if (x > (y = elev[1, 0] + water[1, 0]), \
   -.15 * if (elev > y, water, x - y), \
   .15 * if (elev[1, 0] > x, water[1, 0], y - x))+ \
 if (x > (y = elev[0, -1] + water[0, -1]), \
   -.15 * if (elev > y, water, x - y), \
   .15 * if (elev[0, -1] > x, water[0, -1], y - x))+ \
 if (x > (y = elev[0, 1] + water[0, 1]), \
   -.15 * if (elev > y, water, x - y), \
   .15 * if (elev[0, 1] > x, water[0, 1], y - x))+ \
 if (x > (y = elev[-1, 1] + water[-1, 1]), \
   -.10 * if (elev > y, water, x - y), \
   .10 * if (elev[-1, 1] > x, water[-1, 1], y - x))+ \
 if (x > (y = elev[1, 1] + water[1, 1]), \
   -.10 * if (elev > y, water, x - y), \
   .10 * if (elev[1, 1] > x, water[1, 1], y - x))+ \
 if (x > (y = elev[1, -1] + water[1, -1]), \
   -.10 * if (elev > y, water, x - y), \
   .10 * if (elev[1, -1] > x, water[1, -1], y - x))+ \
 if (x > (y = elev[-1, -1] + water[-1, -1]), \
   -.10 * if (elev > y, water, x - y), \
   .10 * if (elev[-1, -1] > x, water[-1, -1], y - x)))
```

and here the launch script (Spearfish data set: 
http://grass.osgeo.org/download/data.php)

```
#!/bin/sh

g.region rast=elevation.dem -p

r.mapcalc "water = 120" #12 inches of water in each cell

g.copy rast=elevation.dem,elev

d.mon x0
d.rast water
i=1

while [ $i != 100 ]
do
  n=1
  while [ $n != 10 ]
  do
    r.mapcalc < water.mapcalc # run the simulation
    d.rast water
    n=`expr $n + 1`
  done
  g.copy rast=water,water.$i
  i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

hope this helps.

Comment: the water.mapcalc is saved as what format? and where is it saved?

Comment: I tried running it, but it still produced the error: `/c/Program Files/GRASS-64/bin/s1.sh: line 17: water.mapcalc:
No such file or directory`

Comment: Did you run the script in the directory where "water.mapcalc" is stored? If not you need to specify the path to the file or (easier) run all from the same directory.

Comment: Save "water.mapcalc" as ASCII text file.

Comment: thanks. I tried the code with the Spearfish data set. The result of the code is that the map (elevation.dem) is getting smaller every succeeding iteration. I cannot figure out why it is happening. Isn't it that the result for every iteration should just be the transfer of excess height and not the cropping of the edges of the map?